# EHCache with Hibernate Integration Throwing CacheException

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache

I am facing issue in integrating Hibernate And EHCache. I am using Hibernate 3.2.7 GA, Hibernate Annotation 3.2.1 ga,hibernate-commons-annotations 3.2.0.Final, net.sf.ehcache 2.2.0 and Spring version  3.2.4.RELEASE. When I ran my test case I am getting
net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from /content/cache/ehcache.xml. Initial cause was Error configuring from input stream. Initial cause was null:19: Element  does not allow attribute "maxEntriesLocalHeap".

In Hibernate config file i have put 
true

Please help me to solve the issue. I am new to EHCache.

Comment: Can you add the relevant sections of ehcache.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly confident the 2.2 version of Ehcache doesn't support that `maxEntriesLocalHeap`. Any reason you're using such an old version? 
You either need to use a newer one, or modify your ehcache.xml to comply to the 2.2 XSD